# How can I add scrolls to overlapping cards in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of cards within a card.
When I swipe these inner cards, I want the outer card to slide. My outer card has scroll, but when I try to scroll over the inner cards it doesn't work.
When I add scroll to the inner card list, only the cards inside scroll.
How can I make the outer card slide when I try to swipe through the inner card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to Have both ListViews scroll at the same time
that won't happen.

What you should do is to **lock** the inner cards and Display all of them so that the outer card can scroll with them.

in the inner cards, ListView put this:

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
shrinkWrap: true,
```

This should solve your issue.